# Error in Caffe when classifying image using classification.cpp

Tags: c++, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have trained my own network. The training was fine. I have also used 'caffe time' and it estimates time for forward and backward pass normally. However when I run this: [(Using this ref)](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/cpp_classification.html)

```
./build/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin models/own_net/deploy.prototxt examples/RSR_50k_all_1k_db/snapshot_iter_10000.caffemodel examples/RSR_50k_all_1k_db/mean.binaryproto examples/RSR_50k_all_1k_db/labels.txt /home/ubuntu/datasets/RSR_50k_1ll_1k/Testing/[0]/outfile243.jpg
```

This generates an error:

```
F0426 10:10:50.063822  2714 classification.cpp:63] Check failed: net_->num_outputs() == 1 (2 vs. 1) Network should have exactly one output.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @ 0xf6c5d060  (unknown)
    @ 0xf6c5cf5c  (unknown)
    @ 0xf6c5cb78  (unknown)
    @ 0xf6c5ef98  (unknown)
    @     0xd10c  Classifier::Classifier()
    @     0xb0a2  main
    @ 0xf672c632  (unknown)
Aborted
```

When I use the same command to classify the stock cat image using caffenet, it works just fine. I suspect there is a problem with label file. My label file only lists all the labels, one in each line. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

unfortunately, the net is not mine so I don't think I am allowed to share the full structure. However, it has some conv, relu, and fc layers and ends with this layer:

```
layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "ip3"
  top: "prob"
}
```

which I suspect might be the culprit.

Comment: the error is not about the labels, but about the number of outputs in your `deploy.prototxt`. can you link to it?

Comment: according to the error message you get there is another layer that is exposed as output

Comment: @Shai I have update the question. Is this detail sufficient?

Comment: @Shai This is also what I suspected based on various answers on forums. However, I have checked and rechecked and apart from this one, I only have ip, conv, relu, pool and power layers. Can power layer cause this? Can It be due to problems in train_val.prototxt?

Comment: caffe can treat a "top" that is not used as "bottom" in any other layer as an output layer.

Comment: look at the log caffe creates when loading the net it should write what outputs the net bas

Comment: @Shai let me check that too.

Comment: @Shai Thank you! power's top was unused so I was getting this error. However now I get this error:

    `F0426 11:16:21.012200 12999 classification.cpp:254] Check failed: !img.empty() Unable to decode image /home/ubuntu/datasets/RSR_50k_1ll_1k/Testing/[0]/outfile243.jpg`

Comment: @Shai Thank you, the next error was just due to path! Thank you I am getting predictions now :)